# Lost disk after migrating from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: unallocated

After migrating from windows XP (they still exist ;) I "lost" the disk with 3 partitions on it. One of these partitions  was the windows system disk. This disk is now marked as "unallocated". How do I get access to this disk again?

Thnx for helping out...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover your lost data.